# Active Directory "contextless" login with net-ldap

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, netldap

I'm writting a Rails 3.2 application and as authentication I want to use Net::LDAP to connect to the company MS ADDS. I can authenticate a user with Net::LDAP. The problem is that my users exists in different OU's so I would like to do a "contextless" login. Not sure if it is called  contextless in the Microsoft world. I come from a Novell background.

What I meen is to not have to give the FQDN, just the sAMAccountName and password. The :base options seems to lock me in that context and expects the users to exist in that OU alone.

Do I have to bind with a user first(FQDN) then do a filter search or what? Any suggesions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ... I found my answer out there on the net. Thought I would share the answer with you all if it will help someone. Found this wonderful [blog post](http://erniemiller.org/2008/04/04/simplified-active-directory-authentication/) by Ernie Miller from 2008 and it seems to still be valid information. Check it out if you need to.

Best regards
//Roger